# CSS <p> width on percentage online shrinks on window resize (left - right)

Tags: html, css

I have this page (for practicing webprogramming) witch has a footer at the bottom.
http://i333180.iris.fhict.nl/melissa/index.html

Because the site probably got to opened on different window sizes I use margin-top in percentage.

```
margin-top: 38%
```

The problem I got is the footer stays on his place by shrinking the window from bottom to top. But by shrinking the window from left to right, the footer position changes.

I google around and what is said the html, body and surrounded div's has to got

```
height:100%;
```

So added this but the footer won't change position on window resize (bottom-top). Is this only possible to fix with

```
position:absolute;
left: somevalue;
top: somevalue;
```

Comment: Try `vh` instead of `%` (for margin). But either way, consider making it `calc(100vh - something)` if you want it to keep its position at the bottom.

Comment: margin: 60vh 0 0; instead of margin: 35% 0 0 0 works but not al the way!:o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css to the `.p-footer` :

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
left: 25%;
right: 25%;
```

And you should take off the margin property.